# Browse bazaar (or CVS/SVN/Git) repository with GUI?

Tags: user-interface, version-control, browser, ubuntu, bazaar

Is there a nice, open-source, free way to browse a bazaar (or other source control) repository?

What I had in mind is a [wikipedia-history](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Revision_control&action=history)-like browsing, where I can watch and compare any two versions of the code.

**EDIT: I strongly prefer Ubuntu tools.**

Thanks,

Udi

Comment: specifically web based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows *("gui" tag ?)*, what about [TortoiseBzr](http://bazaar-vcs.org/TortoiseBzr) ?

If you want some web-based tool *("browser" tag)*, you can take a look at the [WebInterfaces](http://bazaar-vcs.org/WebInterfaces) page, which lists a couple of possibilities.

[Loggerhead](https://launchpad.net/loggerhead) seems quite good :

> Loggerhead is a web viewer for
>   projects in bazaar. It can be used to
>   navigate a branch history, annotate
>   files, view patches, perform searches,
>   etc. It's originally based on
>   bazaar-webserve, which is itself based
>   on hgweb for Mercurial.

And here is a demo page, that allows you to navigate, see diffs, ... use the application, actually, on a real repository : http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bzr/bzr/trunk/changes

For SVN :

- On WIndows, I'd say [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)
- Web-based, what about [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) ? Here is a [demo](http://demo.websvn.info/listing.php?repname=WebSVN&path=%2Ftrunk%2F#path_trunk_).

For GIT : there is a full/long-list on the [InterfacesFrontendsAndTools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) wiki page.

- Web-based, you could take a look at [gitweb](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/Gitweb) ; here is a [demo](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/warthog9/gitweb.git;a=summary).
- For both GUI and Web based, the list is quite long -- I'll let you go through it by yourself ^^

For CVS : ergh, is anyone still using CVS ? *(yeah, I know, I know...)*

- Web-based : maybe [WebCVS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcvs/) would do ?

You also have plenty of other tootls ; some can even deal with multiple kind of repositories.

For instance, you have [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net/) *(which does more than just repository-browsing ; it's been described as a google-code clone, actually)*.

Comment: Loggerhead seems to be the answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For Bazaar, the [QBzr extensions](http://bazaar-vcs.org/QBzr) give a wide range of q-commands (ex: `bzr qlog`, `bzr qbrowse`)

For Git, there are the `gitk` command and `git gui`

Answer (score 0):

Try [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) or [TortoiseBzr](http://bazaar-vcs.org/TortoiseBzr).

Edit: for Linux, try [rapidsvn](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) and see [these](http://agaric.com/note/subversion-client-ubuntu-anything-tortoisesvn) [discussions](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/58).

Maybe some GUI viewer is available for bazaar on Linux. I have not found one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [QGit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qgit/), which is a bit fiddly but gets the job done. I think I've seen ports of it to other VCS around too.

Answer (score 0):

[ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org) supports web based CVS/SVN repository navigation. If you are looking for a desktop based one you can use TortoiseCVS/SVN or SubClipse etc

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, you should try [Olive](http://bazaar-vcs.org/Olive) for Bazaar and Giggle for Git.

Edit: Don't forget Meld. It is a nice diff/merge tool for Gnome, that works with many version control systems.